# Chrome / FF4 Bug -- Page loads scrolled halfway down

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firefox4

Check out: http://test.pocarr.com/coaching-backing/

In Chrome and FF4, the page loads scrolled halfway down the page. I am completely stumped about what could be causing this. Any ideas?

EDIT: I disabled javascript in my browser, and it still jumps down.

Comment: i dont think its a but in the browser sme `javascript` is doing sme thing in this page

Comment: You disabled context menu? Really?...

Comment: EEK I know. Stubborn client request. I updated the link to one with the context menu enabled.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is caused by `autofocus` attribute on input field. When you set focus (manually or automatically) page scrolls to that element.